# Angular 2 use a "template" for ng-content to use inside component loop

Tags: html, angular

I am trying to create a component that will do some stuff and loop over a result set. I want to be able to provide a "template" for the items in the looped result set.

For instance, this is kind of the idea I am going for:

```
<search-field>
    <ng-template let-item>
        <span><strong>{{item.foo}}</strong></span>
        <span>{{item.bar}}</span>
    </ng-template>
</search-field>
```

The content within the `search-field` component should be used as a template for each iteration of the looped result set within that component.

This is how the `search-field` component may look:

```
<div class="search-container">
    <div class="search-input">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search users..." [(ngModel)]="searchString" (ngModelChange)="searchStringChanged($event)">
        <div class="md-icon">search</div>
    </div>

    <ul class="search-results" *ngIf="searchResults.length > 0">
        <li class="search-results__item" *ngFor="let result of searchResults">
            <ng-content [item]="item"></ng-content> <!-- Template should be used here on each iteration and allow to pass in "item" to use in example up above -->
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How can I pass each item of the loop to the ng-content so that I have access to it in the code of the first example?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Solved this with the following:

Component template usage:

```
<search-field>
    <ng-template let-item>
        <span><strong>{{item.username}}</strong></span>
        <span>{{item.email}}</span>
    </ng-template>
</search-field>
```

Component template definition:

```
<div class="search-container">
    <div class="search-input">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search users..." [(ngModel)]="searchString" (ngModelChange)="searchStringChanged($event)">
        <div class="md-icon">search</div>
    </div>

    <ul class="search-results" *ngIf="searchResults.length > 0">
        <li class="search-results__item" *ngFor="let item of searchResults">
            <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="templateRef" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{$implicit: item}"></ng-template>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Component class:

```
@Component({...})
export class SearchFieldComponent {
    @ContentChild(TemplateRef) templateRef: TemplateRef<any>;

    // ...
}
```

**The explanation:**

Using `ng-template`, I can use the `let-item` syntax, where `item` is the data that will be passed into the template on each iteration of the loop.

And in order to make the above possible, in the `search-field` component I use `ng-template` with `ngTemplateOutlet` as the template reference, and `ngTemplateOutletContext` is given the value `{$implicit: item}`, where `item` is the data I want to pass into the template.

Lastly, in the component class I need to use `ContentChild` to get the reference to the template to use in the `ngTemplateOutlet`.

Comment: Thank you! This approach solves also nested custom components