# Can we pass html template from one component to another component in angular2?

Tags: angular

Suppose i have a base component CardComponent which is resuable ie, it will accept input such as 
1. DataArray 
2. HTML template(that is iterated over)

So consumer component will use CardComponent selector and pass both dataArray and Template.

**How can i achieve it?**  (passing htmltemplate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to pass HTML template using the ng-content approach but you should always go via template approach.

**Your .html file -> Generic ->**

```
<div>
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template"> </ng-container>
 </div>
```

**Your .ts file**

```
    @ContentChild(TemplateRef)
    template: TemplateRef<any>;
```

and **your other component files** from where you want to pass the template:

```
<my-component>
     <ng-template> Your HTML Content </ng-template>
 </my-component>
```

More details regarding why you should consider ng-template instead of

https://medium.com/michalcafe/angulars-content-projection-trap-and-why-you-should-consider-using-template-outlet-instead-cc3c4cad87c9

[Angular 2 use a "template" for ng-content to use inside component loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46810145/angular-2-use-a-template-for-ng-content-to-use-inside-component-loop)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-content tag.

Your reusable component (YOUR-REUSABLE-COMPONENT) template is something like this.

```
<div class="box">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

Usage of your reusable component inside some other component template

```
<YOUR-REUSABLE-COMPONENT>
<div class="class1">
<h1>my main component</h2>
</div>
</YOUR-REUSABLE-COMPONENT>
```

Comment: I dont want in this way, I have done similar kind of implemantion in below link:  
 https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mwyjic?file=app%2Fcardlist%2Fcardlist.component.ts 

I want to know if there is any way, if can receive html as @input, like we receive any other type of data.

Comment: passing an HTML as input not a recommended according to angular guideline.