# How to use transclusion inside *ngFor block in Angular?

Tags: angular

I'm not sure if I'm even using the correct terminology, but here's what I'm trying to do.

I have a grid component:

```
export class GridComponent {

    @Input()
    items: any[];
}
```

In the HTML, I just have this:

```
<div class="grid">
    <ul class="row">
        <li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index;" class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 card-container">
            <ng-content></ng-content>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So essentially, I'm going to pass in items (which could be anything depending on the app requirements), and the component will create a grid for me.

However, I still want the flexibility to construct whatever HTML I want for each iteration of the loop. So I'll need access to each "item" variable of the loop iteration.

I've searched around, and I've come across `ngTemplateOutletContext`. But there are similar things being used as well. Not sure if I'm just getting confused, but I was hoping someone could give me a clear answer on how to solve this issue.

Comment: Check my question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46810145/angular-2-use-a-template-for-ng-content-to-use-inside-component-loop/46810906#46810906) :)

Comment: @Lansana - Thank you! That works great! Quick question though - is there a way to get the index (of the loop iteration) implicitly as well?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46977011/4850646

Comment: @gjvatsalya You can pass in an object with the `$implicit` instead. So instead of `{$implicit: item}`, do something like `{$implicit: {item: item, index: index}}`

Comment: @gjvatsalya You can do as Lansana said, then you would access the index as `{{ item.index }}` (take note that in this way you would call your element as `{{ item.item }}` and not just `{{ item }}`).

Comment: Ah, I see. It works now! Thanks for the help, guys! I really appreciate it.