# How do I find Element inside TemplateRef

Tags: angular

I've been googling around, and am still a bit new to angular 5/6, but I'm trying to see if something is possible.

---

**Problem**

Say I have a template:

```
<ng-template #rt let-r="result" let-t="term">
  <ngb-highlight [result]="r.typeAheadDisplayName" [term]="t" ></ngb-highlight>
  <span *ngIf="r.primaryName ">(alias for {{ r.primaryName }}) </span>{{ r.metaData }}
</ng-template>
```

Within this template a button will generate that can be used as a means of chosing an option. However, for a given reason I need to be able to target `:first-child` of the array of buttons.

I know that I can select the element/template doing:

```
@ViewChild('rt') rt : TemplateRef<any>;
```

but, can I actually do a function similar to jQuery's `.find` or even the same in AngularJS, to target the elements that would be found inside of this template. I've been googling and can't see to find an answer.

Comment: use `rt.nativeElement`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`nativeElement` is what you're looking for. It will give you the native DOM node, and from that you can use methods like `querySelector` to query child nodes.

```
@Component()
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('rt') rt : ElementRef;

    ngOnInit() {
        const childNode = this.rt.nativeElement.querySelector('.child-class');
    }
}
```

**Update:**

For using `ng-template`, you can use `ContentChild` and `TemplateRef` together. `TemplateRef` still has an embedded `ElementRef` within it, so you will still be able to access the `nativeElement` property and do whatever querying you want.

```
<ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="rt"></ng-template>

@Component({selector: 'my-component'})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    @ContentChild('rt') rt: TemplateRef<any>;

    ngOnInit() {
        const childNode = this.rt.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.foo');
    }
}
```

Now you can use that component like so:

```
<my-component>
    <ng-template #rt>
        <div class="foo">Hello world</div>
    </ng-template>
</my-component>
```

Comment: okay, so I'm going to revise my questions because I just realized that this is specifically for an ng-template. QuerySelector isn't a function on templateRef though

Comment: Updated answer. Does that do the trick? By the way, my first solution will still work with a `TemplateRef`, just use `this.rf.elementRef.nativeElement` instead of `this.rt.nativeElement`.

Comment: yes it does, thank you very much. This was very informative.

Comment: Also, take a look at [my question/answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46810145/angular-2-use-a-template-for-ng-content-to-use-inside-component-loop). Might be similar to something you are trying to do, or might be a good bookmark for later:

Comment: I suppose `querySelector` is a Javascript function. Is it safe to use Javascript functions directly in Angular code w.r.t. portability? I would like to avoid mixing Javascript code in Angular code. Do you know a way how to do this without using pure javascript (Renderer2, ViewChild)?

Comment: If you need server-side rendering, etc., then using `querySelector` directly is not good. You can use the `Renderer2` variant. Do a quick search online, but [here is an example you can follow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38944725/how-to-get-dom-element-in-angular-2#38944920).

Comment: For me, `this.rt.elementRef.nativeElement` just returns "comment", not the html element it embeds

Comment: Same as @DongBin Kim, it returns the comment, cant use queryselector either

Comment: @MauroInsacco The Angular API may have changed over time, I'd have to take a look at this code again to give an updated answer. Please refer to the Angular API for the time being, maybe I'll find some time to do this later.