# How do I access a child element in a TemplateRef variable?

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-5

I have a component that includes a modal. The modal is wrapped in a `<ng-template>` tag.

```
<ng-template #modalm let-modal>
...
   <button type="button" (click)="onSubmit()" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>
...
</ng-template>
```

This allows me to open and close the modal from my component.ts file.

```
constructor(private modalService: NgbModal,
    private activeModal: NgbActiveModal)
...
public openModal(modalm: TemplateRef<any>){
    this.activeModal = this.modalService.open(modalm);    
    const btn = modalm.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.btn-primary');
  }
```

I would like to access the button element and set a property on it. I am following the accepted answer in [How do I find Element inside TemplateRef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50417132/how-do-i-find-element-inside-templateref), calling `querySelector` off of `modalm.elementRef.nativeElement`. This gives me an error:

```
TypeError: modalm.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector is not a function
```

Why am I not able to call `querySelector` in this case?

I understand that I have to use the type TemplateRef due to the modal being wrapped in `ng-template`. What is the correct syntax for accessing an element in the modal?

Comment: You should avoid rely on `.querySelector`. Why don't you try to pass the needed option through `NgbModalRef#componentInstance` instead?

Comment: @developer033 I could create a separate component for the modal. Is this required or can I access the html element from the component.ts file of that component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [video from Max NgWizard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qWmqiYDrnDc&list=PLVI0Ut22uwY4UC1v5fUvi2RIU4R4jPkba) pointed me in the right direction. For a TemplateRef instance there isn't a way that I could find that allows ts access to the DOM such that a button property can be set. As the comments indicate, setting element properties in a ts file is also not recommended practice. It is better to put a directive like ngClass in the html markup and look for a flag in the ts file. A class in the component css file can be created for this purpose.

First I create a class ".myClass" with the style properties I need in the component css file. Then I can put a conditional directive on my button to add this class, like

```
<button type="button" (click)="onSubmit()" class="btn btn-primary" [class.myClass]="loadComplete">OK</button>
```

The boolean `loadComplete` controls the application of the css class from within the ts file.

The css class needs the `!important` statement added to override Bootstrap style definitions in my case.

```
.myClass {
    outline: none;
    border: none !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
    -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    color: red !important;
  }
```